# Removing NSNotificationObserver From Different ViewController

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have an observer that I register in one class as so:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

//create shared class reference
var sharedClassReference_A = SharedClass()


//initialize Notification Observer and store observer reference in sharedClass
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var observerHandler: Any? = nil

    observerHandler = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerA.appDidTerminate(_:)), name: .UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)

    self.sharedClassReference_A.sharedHandler = observerHandler

}

//perform some action when a notification is received
@objc func appDidTerminate(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    //perform some action

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueA_X" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ViewControllerX
       destinationController.sharedClassReference_X = self.sharedClassReference_A
    }
}
```

}

I store a reference to the observer in a shared class:

```
class SharedClass {

var sharedHandler: Any? = nil

}
```

I attempt to remove the observer once I reach a different view controller as so:

```
class ViewControllerX: UIViewController {

var sharedClassReference_X = SharedClass()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //Attempt to remove observer registered in ViewControllerA
    if let observerHandler = self.sharedClassReference_X.sharedHandler {
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observerHandler)
    }
}

}
```

I know that removing the observer using this approach is failing, because the observer is getting called after ViewControllerX is deallocated.

My question is: How can I successfully initialize an observer in one class (ViewControllerA) and be able to remove it later in a different class (ViewControllerX)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to follow the general guidelines of setting the observers inside `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear` and removing them inside   `deinit` / `viewDidDisappear` respectively according to your case , as this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerA.appDidTerminate(_:)), name: .UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

returns **void**

//

```
class ViewControllerX: UIViewController { 
   var aRef:ViewControllerA!
}
```

in prepareForSegue

```
destinationController.aRef = self
```

Then use

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(aRef, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

Comment: Isn't this line of code creating a shared state between the two instances?:
"destinationController.sharedClassReference_X = self.sharedClassReference_A".
Therefore, aren't they the same instance, and NOT 2 separate instances? 

I need to remove the observer in a different view controller, and can't simply use the approach of "viewWillAppear" and "viewWillDisappear" that you recommended, because the approach you recommended ONLY applies to removing observers within the same view controller class

Comment: Ok. Then how can I remove the observer I initialized in controllerA from controllerX? 
Simply calling "NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)" in controllerX will not work either

Comment: And I see now that the "observer" parameter refers to the "observing object" itself...